# Toggle classname based on DOM value and state comparison

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a personal portfolio with React which fetch data from json and render it. The projects component part is where i have some difficulties. I'm rendering the projects under categories but my problem is that I created a switch slider selector where I can select a category but I don't know how I change the classname of the slider options based on the current state.

Here's the code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SectionWrap from './sectionWrap'; 

class Projects extends Component { 
  state = {
    switchState: "All"
  }

  // renderProjects function is just rendering jsx based on imported json file (nothing important)

  switchCurrentState = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      switchState: e.target.innerHTML
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SectionWrap id="projects" name="Projects">
        <div className="switchWrap">
          <a className="switch" href="#" onClick={this.switchCurrentState}>All</a>
          <a className="switch" href="#" onClick={this.switchCurrentState}>Graphic</a>
          <a className="switch" href="#" onClick={this.switchCurrentState}>Web</a>
          <a className="switch" href="#" onClick={this.switchCurrentState}>Photography</a>
          <a className="switch switchOn" href="#" onClick={this.switchCurrentState}>Video</a>
        </div>
        <div className="projectsWrap">
          {this.state.switchState == "All" ? this.renderProjects("All") : this.renderProjects(this.state.switchState)}
        </div>
      </SectionWrap>
    );
  }
}

export default Projects;
```

What I want to do is adding a classname "switchOn" whenever the switch is active, something like:

```js
className={`switch ${this.state.switchState === this.value ? 'switchOn' : ''}`
```

where `this.value` is the value/text of the div.

Comment: First on your onClick handlers you will need top bind them {this.switchCurrentCase.bind(this)} To set a class based on state you pretty much had it.. className={this.state.switchState  === "All" ? "switchOn" : ""} you will have to specifically check for each category on each link. Also you should use buttons instead of anchor tags. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SectionWrap from './sectionWrap'; 

const switches = ["All", "Web", "Graphic", "Photography", "Video"];

class Projects extends Component { 
  state = {
    switchState: "All"
  }

  // renderProjects function is just rendering jsx based on imported json file (nothing important)

  switchCurrentState = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      switchState: e.target.innerHTML
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SectionWrap id="projects" name="Projects">
        <div className="switchWrap">
          { switches.map(switch => 
            (<a 
               className=`switch ${this.state.switchState === switch : "switchOn" : ""}`
               href="#" 
               onClick={this.switchCurrentState}
             >
                 { switch }
             </a>)
            )
          }
        </div>
        <div className="projectsWrap">
          {this.renderProjects(this.state.switchState)}
        </div>
      </SectionWrap>
    );
  }
}

export default Projects;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the previous one was good also but I chose this one for code beauty reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have already answered your own question, but instead of using  `this.value` or put in that big conditional in each classname write a helper function:

```
activeClassname(matchText) {
  if(this.state.switchState === matchText) {
    return 'switchOn';
  }
  return '';
}
```

then in your links:

```
<a className={`switch ${activeClassname('All')}`} href="#" onClick={this.switchCurrentState}>All</a>
<a className={`switch ${activeClassname('Graphic')}`} href="#" onClick={this.switchCurrentState}>Graphic</a>
<a className={`switch ${activeClassname('Web')}`} href="#" onClick={this.switchCurrentState}>Web</a>
<a className={`switch ${activeClassname('Photography')}`} href="#" onClick={this.switchCurrentState}>Photography</a>
<a className={`switch ${activeClassname('Video')}`} href="#" onClick={this.switchCurrentState}>Video</a>
```

Comment: I didn't know how I didn't had this simple idea thank your very much, problem solved.